# Alarm about Internet usage?

Tags: data-monitoring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Monitor wifi usage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15066/monitor-wifi-usage)

Is there a way to have an alarm warn me every time I spent another 100MB and telling me the total I've spent on the last billing period to avoid going over my limit and into debt in Android?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [NetCounter](http://www.jaqpot.net/netcounter/) will do what you need

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [Network Monitor](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.aob.android.mnm). With this free app you can track 2G/3G and WiFi traffic as separate stats. Also you can set up warning message for each stat.