# How to monitor Wi-Fi usage?

Tags: wi-fi, data-monitoring

Is it possible to monitor Wi-Fi usage in a similar method to how 3g watchdog monitors 3G usage?    I have android 2.2 on my phone.  I doesn't need to do everything 3G watchdog does, all I need to see is how much data I am using.

Comment: Recent update has made 3g watchdog  monitor to show wifi usage as well :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Netcounter](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.jaqpot.netcounter) can monitor both cellular data and wifi usage levels.

Answer (score 4):

[My Data Manager](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.mobidia.android.mdm&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5tb2JpZGlhLmFuZHJvaWQubWRtIl0.) also does a great job.

Tracks wifi and cellular down to the app level.  You can have it warn you when you are near a data cap. You can set it up to track by calendar month or by your billing cycle.

It has a widget as well as a notification bar item.

I used it to track down my runaway data usage (Doggcatcher) on my phone as well as a build.prop error causing huge data usage on my son's MIUI Incredible.

Comment: MDM looks great... It has clean UI, too.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [DU Meter for Android](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.hageltech.dumeter&hl=en). DU Meter can show current network transfer rates in the notification area, it includes a home screen widget which displays daily or monthly data usage, etc.

[image]   [image]

Disclaimer: I'm the author of DU Meter.

Answer (score 0):

For more options, you can also try [Traffic Monitor](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.radioopt.widget&hl=en); it monitors both cellular and wifi usage as well. And you can also check usage per app.