# How do I check which apps are using wifi?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, miui

I'm using the red mi 2 and data transfer is taking place via wifi, problem is I don't know which app is using it. Is there a way to see wifi usage statistics?

Comment: Related http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15066/how-to-monitor-wi-fi-usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For even more detail, I recommend [Trepn Profiler](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.quicinc.trepn) from the Play store. It's developed by Qualcomm and analyses CPU usage, Wifi and cellular data usage, and more.

Answer (score 5):

Go to: *Settings > Data usage – WIRELESS & NETWORKS*

1. Tap the right-top menu. It will open up a popup menu.
2. Check *Show Wi-Fi usage.
3. Go to *Data Usage*. You'll realize a new tab called WIFI is added nexto to MOBILE.
4. There, you can see all apps that use WIFI and how much data they use.

> [image: screenshot] [image: screenshot] [image: screenshot]
>   <sup>Visual how-to (source: [TeckFront](http://teckfront.com/view-data-usage-wi-fi-android-4-4-kitkat-device/); click images for larger variants)</sup>