# LG G5 Slowing Down house internet (Problem found)

Tags: wi-fi

2 days ago I posted a question

[LG G5 Slowing down the house internet](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/155101/lg-g5-slowing-down-the-house-internet)

regarding an LG G5 slowing down the internet drastically. After a suggestion I saw in the comments to see what is using the most data I found a suprising result.

[image: Before 22/7/16]
[image: After 22/7/16]

My sister owns a lot of photos, but we know people who do the same and won't experience this issue.

Is this a problem with the application itself? something in the settings that is wrong? How do I fix that?

Comment: Quite surprising, as you said. See, Google Photos usually backups any photo under the DCIM folder to Google servers. You may want to try a different gallery, and see if the problem solves itself.